# Unwanted query optimisation in nested view

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, data-warehouse, nested-views

I've got a SQL Server data warehouse with a [Fact Constellation Schema](http://datawarehouse4u.info/Data-warehouse-schema-architecture-fact-constellation-schema.html) design. I've got to build a report on 4 objects/views:

1. Sales actuals - fact table [Sales]
2. Sales targets - fact table [Targets]
3. Stocks        - fact table [Inventory]
4. Inbound       - fact table [Transit]

All the objects/views have the same signature, for example:

```
Sales actuals: ProductID, RegionID, SalesManagerID, ..., <product data>, <region data>, ..., Quantity;
Sales targets: ProductID, --null--, SalesManagerID, ..., <product data>, -----null----, ..., Quantity;
Stocks:        ProductID, RegionID, -----null-----, ..., <product data>, <region data>, ..., Quantity;
...
```

To achieve such a signature, each object/view is sourced from a fact table and 5-6 dimension tables. Dimension tables are shared between objects (table with product data, table with region data, ...).

It doesn't take SQL more than 5-10 seconds to calculate each view.

NOW that I want to combine them in a single report, I'm doing this:

```
Select * from [Sales actuals]
UNION
Select * from [Sales targets]
UNION
Select * from [Stocks]
UNION
Select * from [Inbound]
```

And here SQL doesn't even manage to retrieve 10% of data within 1 minute. It seems that the query optimizer combines 4 fact tables into one large vector and attaches dimension table - which drives the system crazy.

What I want is to keep views/objects encapsulated. That means, the engine must calculate the views first (4 * 5 secs = 20 secs). and only then apply Union operation (10 secs + some overhead) to retrieve the result.

Question: how can I disable query optimization in nested views to achieve such "computational encapsulation"?

Doing like the compiler does: union the fact tables first and then join the dimension tables - is no option, because I want to keep code interpretable and reusable.

Thanks in advance!
Constantine

Comment: I would think if you select into 4 temporary tables and then union those, you might get what you want to achieve.

Comment: Try to change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`. Union can take much time because it removes duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you probably want to change `UNION` into `UNION ALL` ?!?

To have the server do what you want you could add the `NOEXPAND` table hint in the 'final' view; but to be honest I've never seen it being beneficial to overall performance.

I'm wondering how smart the query optimizer would be if you tried something along the lines of :

```
;WITH facts (dimension_ids & measures)
         AS (Select * from [Sales actuals]
             UNION ALL
             Select * from [Sales targets]
             UNION ALL
             Select * from [Stocks]
             UNION ALL
             Select * from [Inbound])
SELECT dimension_values, measures
  FROM facts
  JOIN dimension1 ON dim1.id = facts.dim1_id
                 AND dim1.property = @filter_dim1 
  JOIN dimension2 ON dim2.id = ...

etc...
```

It probably would do what you want, although I'm not convinced it would be better than

```
SELECT dimension_values, measures
  FROM [Sales actuals] fct
  JOIN dimension1 ON dim1.id = fct.dim1_id
                 AND dim1.property = @filter_dim1 
  JOIN dimension2 ON dim2.id = ...

UNION ALL 

SELECT dimension_values, measures
  FROM [Sales targets] fct
  JOIN dimension1 ON dim1.id = fct.dim1_id
                 AND dim1.property = @filter_dim1 
  JOIN dimension2 ON dim2.id = ...

UNION ALL
etc...
```

which --going by your explanation-- is what you're running up against and apparently has terrible performance ?

PS: I know this will sound 'basic', but did you run sp_updatestats first ?